# How do I create a preview of text being input as it happens in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm new to React. What I'm trying to do is create a form. You type a message and beneath it is a box that shows a preview of the message as you're typing it. For ex, you type "a" in the input box, "a" simultaneously appears in the preview box.

This is what I have (this is also my first post here. I apologize if I did anything incorrectly):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const kInitialFormData = {
    message: '',
};

const NewForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(kInitialFormData);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const message = event.target.message;

        setFormData(prev => ({
            ...prev, [message]: value
        }));
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleSubmit({ ...formData });
        setFormData(kInitialFormData);
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="message">Message: </label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                id="message"
                name="message"
                value={formData.message}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input type="submit" value="Post Message" />
        </form>
    );
};

export default NewForm;
```

I tried making sure onChange and my values are correct. They seem ok to me. I'm currently not able to type in the box but I can see it and the button when the page is rendered. Unsure if it's related.

Comment: `event.target.message` is wrong, try debugging with a breakpoint to inspect its value. You either want `[event.target.name]: value` or just hardcode it to `["message"]: value` or `message: value`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you expect:

```
const message = event.target.message;

setFormData(prev => ({
    ...prev, [message]: value
}));
```

If there *is* an `event.target.message`, it isn't your "message" value.  (If there isn't, it's `undefined`.)  Whatever `message` is here, this is setting a property *named for its value*.  So, for example, if `message` were the string `"test"` (it isn't, but just for illustration), then this effectively does this:

```
setFormData(prev => ({
    ...prev, test: value
}));
```

The value you need is simply `value`.  And the property on your object is called `message`.  So just set your `message` property to that value:

```
setFormData(prev => ({
    ...prev, message: value
}));
```

And you don't need the `message` variable at all in that function.

Comment: I see! I thought it was holding whatever the message was. I made that change and it's allowing me to enter text into the field now, thank you!

Comment: Why is this answer not marked as accepted?